# Django exclude field in admin if creator of this object is request user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can I exclude a field from the Django admin if the creator of this object is current user. Is there any way to customise my model in `admin.py`?

```
class Toys(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='Item_tags')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you showed your model and model admin, and said which field you want to exclude.

Comment: edited my question and field is status which i want to be excluded

Comment: You're not storing the creator in the model, so you can't tell whether a user is the creator or not.

Comment: i'll add new field this is not a problem. i need to know how to customise this in my admin.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add a field to your model to store the creator.

```
class Toys(BaseModel):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='Item_tags')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The override the [`get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) method of your model admin.

```
class ToyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(ToyAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        if obj is not None and request.user.is_authenticated():  # In Django 1.10+ use request.user.is_authenticated
            if obj.creator == request.user:
            fields = [f for f in fields if f != 'status']
        return fields
```

In Django 1.11+, you can use [`get_exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_exclude) instead.

```
class ToyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None and request.user.is_authenticated():  # In Django 1.10+ use request.user.is_authenticated
            if obj.creator == request.user:
                return ['status']
        else:
            return []
```

Comment: and one question how can i make that user creating object can't see pending.(i tried exclude but other users won't be able to see this field) any suggestions?

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue. Please ask a new question.